# R: Extract last N words from character column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I was hoping for some help with extracting the last N words from a column in a data.table.. and then assigning it to a new column.

```
 test <- data.table(original = c('the green shirt totally brings out your eyes'
                               , 'ford focus hatchback'))
```

The original data.table looks like this:

```
original
1: the green shirt totally brings out your eyes
2: ford focus hatchback
```

I want to subset out (up to) the last 5 words into a new column, **so the output looks like**:

```
original                                        extracted
1: the green shirt totally brings out your eyes totally brings out your eyes
2: ford focus hatchback                         ford focus hatchback
```

I tried:

```
  test <- test[, extracted := paste0(tail(strsplit(original, ' ')[[1]], 5)
                                   , collapse = ' ')]
```

and it almost works, except that the 1st value in the 'extracted' column is repeated throughout the new column:

```
original                                        extracted
1: the green shirt totally brings out your eyes totally brings out your eyes
2: ford focus hatchback                         totally brings out your eyes
```

For the life of me I can't figure this out.  I tried the 'word' function from 'stringr' which gives me the last word, but I can't seem to count backwards.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use

```
n = 5
patt = sprintf("\\w+( \\w+){0,%d}$", n-1)

library(stringi)
test[, ext := stri_extract(original, regex = patt)]

                                       original                          ext
1: the green shirt totally brings out your eyes totally brings out your eyes
2:                         ford focus hatchback         ford focus hatchback
```

*Comments:*

- This breaks if you set `n=0`, but there's probably no good reason to do that.
- This is vectorized, in case you have `n` differing across rows (e.g., `n=3:4`).
- **@eddi provided a base analogue** (for fixed `n`):

  ```
  test[, ext := sub('.*?(\\w+( \\w+){4})$', '\\1', original)]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Base R solution:

```
test[,extracted:=sapply(strsplit(original,'\\s+'),function(v) paste(collapse=' ',tail(v,5L)))];
##                                        original                    extracted
## 1: the green shirt totally brings out your eyes totally brings out your eyes
## 2:                         ford focus hatchback         ford focus hatchback
```